# Neural Network Layer Output Calculation: Why is it xA instead of Ax?

Tags: matrix-calculus, neural-networks

"In a neural network, if the first layer has 'm' neurons and the second layer has 'n' neurons, the layer weight is defined as an m*n matrix.
My question is, if 'x' is the input to the first layer, to calculate the output of the second layer (without considering the activation function), we should compute xA, not Ax. This seems a bit odd to me, as in the multiplication between a matrix and a vector, the matrix usually comes first. Could anyone explain why this is the case?"

Comment: It's also possible to multipy a matrix on the right of a row vector, although I can't personally check if this is your case.

Comment: The convention on whether vectors are row or column by default (which determines whether a matrix comes first in a product) varies across mathematics (Although most of the time column vectors are standard). I think that statistics in particular tends to use the row vector convention.

Comment: @Fishbane People who have gone too deep into algebra will tell you the horrible truth, i.e. that if your scalar multipication is $\alpha v$ (i.e. on the left), then the vector should be row and matrices should be on the right (i.e. $\alpha vA$); and if you want column vectors then matrices should be on the left and scalars should be on the right, like $Av\alpha$.

Comment: @DumperDGarb Even with that "horrible truth", we could just consider $R^{\text{op}}$-modules instead of $R$-modules, so it would still come down to a choice.

Comment: @DumperDGarb To be really technically correct scalar multiplication is a seperate operation to multiplication by a $1 \times1$ matrix and so you can have scalar multiples on the left. However if you for example multiply a row and column matrix to get a $1 \times1 $ matrix then it should go on the right in a product. In other words you are half right.

Comment: Does $AB$ mean we apply $A$ first and then $B$ or $B$ first and then $A$?  Some people prefer the former, which leads us to $xA$ rather than $Ax$.  (_I will say nothing of the monsters who write $B(Ax) = (AB)x$_)

Comment: Not sure which reference you are using, but usually for a neural network, we define the output of a linear layer for **a single sample** as $x↦Ax$. However, we usually consider (mini-)batches of data, which are stacked into a matrix $X$, where the $k$-row is the $k$-th sample $x_k$. Then transforming each sample by $x_k↦Ax_k$ and stacking the results into rows again is equivalent to $X↦ XA^⊤$.

This sometimes confuses people since now the 'x' appears left to the matrix, but you can verify yourself that it gives the correct result.